# Rails with Passenger not loading all gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm wondering whats happening here. I have a rails app on my own machine that is working fine. I copied it onto a Dreamhost server with Passenger installed and it said it would magically start with no other needed work.

However, it seems that all the gems are not loading. So I went in and created a new gem set with all the needed gems. Still, I'm seeing the same error. What should I do? Do I need to restart Passenger or something like that, so that it recognizes the new gems?

The error I'm seeing is

```
It is possible that you didn't upload 
your application files correctly. Please check whether all 
your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all 
libraries that this application requires.
```

edit: trace

```
0     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `gem_original_require'
1     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `require'
2     /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    155 in `require'
3     /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/app/helpers/application_helper.rb    4
4     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `gem_original_require'
5     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `require'
6     /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    155 in `require'
7     /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    262 in `require_or_load'
8     /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    221 in `depend_on'
9     /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    133 in `require_dependency'
10  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb   193 in `default_helper_module!'
11  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb   208 in `__send__'
12  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb   208 in `inherited'
13  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/app/controllers/application.rb 4
14  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
16  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  155 in `require'
17  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  262 in `require_or_load'
18  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  221 in `depend_on'
19  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  133 in `require_dependency'
20  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb    18  in `define_dispatcher_callbacks'
21  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 182 in `call'
22  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 182 in `evaluate_method'
23  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 166 in `call'
24  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 90  in `run'
25  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 90  in `each'
26  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 90  in `send'
27  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 90  in `run'
28  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb 277 in `run_callbacks'
29  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb   559 in `send'
30  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb   559 in `prepare_dispatcher'
31  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb   173 in `process'
32  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb   112 in `send'
33  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb   112 in `run'
34  /home/mtaysic/taysic.com/config/environment.rb  17
35  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
36  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
37  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb    299 in `preload_application'
38  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb    248 in `initialize_server'
```

Comment: Could you post more of the error? Perhaps the stack trace?

Comment: yes thanks. the whole thing is here: http://www.taysic.com/

Comment: Your actual error is this: `no such file to load -- htmlentities (MissingSourceFile)`. Make sure it's installed and that you've got a reference to it in either environment.rb or your Gemfile (depending if you're using Rails 2 or 3

Comment: I strongly recommend using bundler, even if on rails 2 you can manually install bundler. Bundler also has a deploy production flag to install all required gems. This is done automatically if you use capistrano with the correct bundler require in your capfile.
Please ignore this if you already use bundler or rails 3 :)